# How to improve this pandas code "Dropping of nuisance columns in DataFrame reductions (with 'numeric_only=None') is deprecated"

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I have a CSV with more than 500.000 results with a lot of duplicates, I'm creating a new dataframe with unique values and trying to find the min value of a date.

I have this code here that works but takes way to much time to load. How can I improve this?

```
for i in range(len(df_leads)):
    df_leads.loc[i,'Created Date'] = df[df['customer_lead_id'] == df_leads.loc[i,'Lead']].min()['created_date']
```

Comment: You say you _have a CSV_, while your _code_ has two data frames; how comes? Some sample data would be in order.

Comment: The second df comes from doing the unique of df['customer_lead_id']

Answer (score 0):

> I'm creating a new dataframe with unique values and trying to find the min value of a date.
>
> The second df comes from doing the unique of df['customer_lead_id']

Instead of that, we can [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) in a DataFrame after we [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) of the date - this will keep the first occurrence, i. e. *the min value*:

```
df.sort_values('created_date').drop_duplicates('customer_lead_id')
```